# Should downvoting an answer on a question where you have an answer cost more reputation?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have had this happen a couple of times, or at least that's what I can gather. Someone, usually a relatively new user that has been on *just* long enough to downvote, answers the same question as me. My answers in these cases had nothing disagreeable about them and were otherwise pretty well-received. But my best guess is that in order to make their answer look better and rise to the top, they downvote my answer. Downvoting answers costs 1 reputation, but shouldn't it cost more if you have an answer on the same question? Maybe 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The martial arts StackExchange site has no control over this policy. There is a lot of network-wide consideration that has gone into the current settings over the years, and it is unlikely these will be changed.

See, for example:
[Should the weight of downvotes be increased?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased)

Comment: Would this be a better question to ask in SE Meta?

Comment: @LemmyX - You can ask, but it will most likely be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: The subject of *down voting with no apparent good reason* has also been well discussed over the years, and the answer is (paraphrased): *it happens, get used to it, there's no practical way to make any effective change in this area*.